# Change the size of a specific context menu entry?

Tags: gtk, size, menu

Is there a way to change the size of one specific context menu entry of GTK+ applications?

Preferably without requiring superuser privileges.

Why? In some applications, I use one specific context menu entry 99% of the time. Often enough I misclick, and, depending on the application, have to undo whatever happenend when clicking the wrong context menu entry.

So when I could make the intended entry bigger, the probability of misclicks should be lowered.

Comment: I’m not sure if this would depend on OS or DE (I thought I could keep the question general by not narrowing it down), but if it’s important: I’m using Debian with XFCE (but I’m interested in GNOME 2, too).

Comment: Which menu item is this? I doubt that GTK treats any of them differently though. I would imagine there is a single menu item style and that is applied to all items.

Comment: @terdon: For example, the context menu of a track in [Quod Libet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quod_Libet_%28software%29): it contains the entry "Edit tags", which I want to become bigger than the other entries. I figured that if it’s possible at all, the solution should work for all GTK+ programs in the same way, so I didn’t include the specific program in my question. Is this a wrong assumption?

Comment: No, I think it is a very valid assumption. That's what I mean, I imagine there is simply a definition of a menu item and all menu items follow it. I don't think there will be a way of changing only some items and not others. Haven't seen the code but I can only imagine you would have to write a hack that creates a new class of object, BigMenu or whatever, and then change the relevant menu items to be of that class. I would be very surprised of you can do that without modifying somebody's source code.